Distribution of the sample covariance of a multivariate exponential family
I am wondering if there is a known form for the distribution of the sample covariance matrix of a random variable that follows a multivariate exponential family distribution. I guess it would be a generalization of the Wishart distribution for the multivariate normal distribution.
